# Recursion in SQL For each movie that is the last of the series, find the first movie of the series and output the IDs of the corresponding movie pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I am struggling with the following problem

I have two relations

1. movies with the attributes id, title and year
2. sequels with the attributes predecessor and successor, which are foreign keys on id

I want to have a recursive SQL query that for each movie that is the last of the series, calculates the first movie of the series, and outputs the IDs of the corresponding movie pairs

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Don't forget to include your current SQL attempt.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.